# YARP proxy with Redisinsight

Tags: c#, .net, redis, ms-yarp

has anyone managed to set up a YARP configuration for RedisInsight in Docker, which runs on localhost:8001? I would need to redirect myserver/app/redis to localhost:8001. When I tried it, I had a problem with loading JavaScript scripts, etc., because they are being searched for on myserver. Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance.

I tried setting RIPROXYPATH for RedisInsight but that doesn't work.

Comment: You have to change the default listening port for docker on server.  See https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3968

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaroslav Nerusil, can you please share the logs as well?

For RedisInsight v1, you'll have to set `RIPROXYENABLE` and set the path in `RIPROXYPATH` for RedisInsight to serve the application in a subpath.

While this is there, you don't need to forward the traffic to localhost:8001 on your web server because all the requests will always be made to the subpath and never to the root path. So, there is no need for any webserver configuration apart from serving the root application itself.

Here's a sample nginx setup - https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight-reverse-proxy/blob/main/nginx-subpath-proxy/nginx-subpath-proxy.conf.template